# React Native - React.createElement is Not a Function

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

Figured I would see what React Native is all about, so I followed the instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content) and can't even get the out of the box project to run correctly.  Chrome dev tools throws all sorts of errors.  Here is the stack trace shown in the simulator, anybody else run into this?

[image: React.createElement is not a function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what may have happened here is that you named your project "React". The CLI replaces the word "SampleApp" with the name that you specified in the sample files that it generates.

This is the original file here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/SampleApp/index.ios.js You can see where it has "SampleApp" in a few places where on your file has "React" for all of them.

It really wasn't your fault, the CLI just needs to be a little smarter and not allow someone to create a project named "React". :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I used different version of JSXTransformer.js and react.js . Using 0.13.3 from cdn solved the problem. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react/